How can I differentiate between 0 values and null/blank values in Google Sheets?
I am trying to automate the creation of charts which display power readings over the last eight quarters for a piece of equipment. I am using a pivot table to filter the raw data before converting it into a chart, but I realize that the table is converting blanks from the raw data into zeros on the chart. This is causing my power readings to look they are dropping to zero, when in fact the equipment was just out of commission or the voltage readings were skipped that quarter.
I would just create a chart and manually filter the data, but I have multiple pieces of equipment with multiple power charts each that I want to be able to see all at once.
Pivot Table Example



Date
L1/L2
L1/L3
L2/L3
L1
L2
L3




03/03/2023
0
0
0
0
0
0


05/09/2023
476
478
478
0.31
0.32
0.36


08/08/2023
0
0
0
0.33
0.32
0.22


11/02/2023
487
488
490
0.18
0.22
0.19


02/09/2024
481
482
484
0.35
0.34
0.29


05/14/2024
479
481
479
0.31
0.32
0.36


08/07/2024
479
481
483
0.6
0.6
0.6


11/06/2024
484
484
487
0.2
0.3
0.2



In the example above, this machine was out of service on 3/3/23 and the voltage readings were skipped on 8/8/23. The raw data is blank, not zero (which is a big difference). Instead of reporting those as blanks, the pivot table is converting to zero. This is an issue because when feeding the data to a chart I get something like this:

How can generate charts where blanks and zeros in the original data are differentiated?

Have you considered using a method other than a pivot to create the chart. For example, query displays  blanks as blanks.

If your data range have real blanks instead of zeros, it can be done by selecting the Customize menu for Chart Style and selecting the checkbox near Plot null values option. It will be like in the image https://i.sstatic.net/Kn5LqfbG.png

Further to my previous comment... If, say, you select a criterion from dropdown then you can not only use the value of the dropdown in your query filter but you can also use it as a Column header. As I recently found out.
